# select from more than two tables each having no relation

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have three different types of transaction tables which hold data for 3 different type of transactions.
I have to display data from each of these but the problem is that I have to mix these rows and sort according to date.
for eg I have transac1,transac2,transac1 and a user table.
transac1 be like

```
id txn_id user_id field_a date
1   223    1       23   12/12/12
2   r23    1       33   12/12/12
```

transac2 be like

```
id txn_id user_id field_b date
1   nne    1       53     12/12/12
2   wr3    1       93     11/12/12
```

transac3 be like

```
id txn_id user_id field_c  date
1   g4t3    1       73     12/12/12
2   d3ts    1       83     12/12/12
```

and when i get the data from these the data should be like

```
id row_id txn_id user_id field_a field_b field_c table_name date
1  2   wr3        1       0       93      0      transac_2   11/12/12
2  1   223        1       23      0       0      transac_1   12/12/12
3  2   r23        1       33      0       0      transac_1   12/12/12
4  1   nne        1       0       53      0      transac_2   12/12/12
5  1   g4t3       1       0       0       73     transac_3   12/12/12
6  2   dt3s       1       0        0      83     transac_3   12/12/12
```

data should be sorted according to this date and table will have joins with some other table separately.
Any body Know how can I do this. By the way , I am using Codeigniter framework if its possible with query builder of CI the it would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: use `union` or `union all`. Refer this link . > https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp

Comment: @chiragpatel Yeah some one suggested me that too, but I really don't know how to use that. Can you please write a query for me and is it possible with query builder of CI because its easy to modify later

Comment: ok , i give you answer .

Comment: @prabhjot wrote the description and query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution:

> This solution is for **WITH ROW NUMBER**

```
SELECT  @rownum := @rownum + 1 rownum , t.*
 FROM ( 
                 select id,txn_id,user_id,field_a, 0 as field_b, 0 as field_c,
                     'transac_1' as table_name , date from transac_1
               UNION ALL 
                 select id,txn_id,user_id,0 as field_a, field_b, 0 as field_c,
                     'transac_2' as table_name , date from transac_2
               UNION ALL
                 select id,txn_id,user_id,0 as field_a, 0 as field_b, field_c,
                     'transac_3' as table_name , date from transac_3 
    )t , (SELECT @rownum := 0) r Order by t.date desc
```

> This solution is for **WITHOUT ROW NUMBER**

```
 SELECT  t.*
     FROM ( 
                     select id,txn_id,user_id,field_a, 0 as field_b, 0 as field_c,
                         'transac_1' as table_name , date from transac_1
                   UNION ALL 
                     select id,txn_id,user_id,0 as field_a, field_b, 0 as field_c,
                         'transac_2' as table_name , date from transac_2
                   UNION ALL
                     select id,txn_id,user_id,0 as field_a, 0 as field_b, field_c,
                         'transac_3' as table_name , date from transac_3 
        )t Order by t.date desc
```

I hope this solution helpful to you. Let me know if you want anything else or this solution is not work for you.

Comment: let me try,wait

Comment: well row number is not important , and by the way it as whole worked for me but I am wondering how i will sort the new table according to 'created' field

Comment: means sort by date field ?

Comment: yeah , and I think utsav , you and Danyal have similar answer

Comment: if this answer is helpful to you then don't forgot to mark is as accepted. so this answer is helpful to others

Comment: what is this for ?  (SELECT @rownum := 0)

Comment: this is for set @rownum variable value to 0.

Comment: Yeah well thanks for your answer , Wish I had listened to the teacher in the class when this was being taught

Comment: select id need to be select id as row_id

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo yeah you are right but as I am going to use the query without row number and the field id is in all tables so its not going to create any problem.

Answer (score 1):

- Create a variable to generate new sequence:
- Make sure you use `union all` not `union` (as union will discard
  duplicates)

  ```
  set @var:=;
  select @var:=@var+1, * from ( 
  select id as row_id, ..... from table_1
   union all 
   select id as row_id, ..... from table_2
  ) as alais
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

[Rextester Sample](http://rextester.com/CGTLCG79686)

```
select @rownum:=@rownum+1 as id, t.* from
(
select id as row_id,txn_id,user_id,field_a,0 as field_b,0 as field_c,
'transac_1' as table_name,date
from transac1
union all
select id as row_id,txn_id,user_id,0 as field_a,field_b,0 as field_c,
'transac_2' as table_name,date
from transac2
union all
select id as row_id,txn_id,user_id,0 as field_a,0 as field_b,field_c,
'transac_3' as table_name,date
from transac3
) t , (SELECT @rownum:=0) r
order by t.date;
```

Output:

```
+----+--------+--------+---------+---------+---------+---------+------------+---------------------+
| id | row_id | txn_id | user_id | field_a | field_b | field_c | table_name |        date         |
+----+--------+--------+---------+---------+---------+---------+------------+---------------------+
|  1 |      2 | wr3    |       1 |       0 |      93 |       0 | transac_2  | 12.11.2012 00:00:00 |
|  2 |      2 | d3ts   |       1 |       0 |       0 |      83 | transac_3  | 12.12.2012 00:00:00 |
|  3 |      1 | nne    |       1 |       0 |      53 |       0 | transac_2  | 12.12.2012 00:00:00 |
|  4 |      1 | 223    |       1 |      23 |       0 |       0 | transac_1  | 12.12.2012 00:00:00 |
|  5 |      1 | g4t3   |       1 |       0 |       0 |      73 | transac_3  | 12.12.2012 00:00:00 |
|  6 |      2 | r23    |       1 |      33 |       0 |       0 | transac_1  | 12.12.2012 00:00:00 |
+----+--------+--------+---------+---------+---------+---------+------------+---------------------+
```